# Azure hosted agents - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, build-agent

I set up a hosted agent in Azure to do a CI build but I'm getting the following warning during the Visual Studio build step before the build fails:

"Visual Studio version '15.0' not found. Looking for the latest version."

Looking at the documentation for hosted agents it looks like they're not deployed with Visual Studio 2017:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted

Does anyone know when the hosted agents will be deployed with Visual Studio 2017 or when this will be likely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 online build agent fails due to inability to find Visual Studio Version 15.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41745268/visual-studio-2017-online-build-agent-fails-due-to-inability-to-find-visual-stud)

Comment: @rboe This question was asked a while back when VS 2017 had not been released, I found it before posting my question. Now it has been released I would've assumed Microsoft will update the hosted agents, I'm not asking for a workaround but when the hosted agents will have VS 2017 installed.

Answer (score 3):

When selecting your agent queue, you can now select the "Hosted VS2017".

You may need to adapt your build pipeline. For instance I had to remove the Nuget Restore step I had and just ticked the "restore nuget package" in the build step. The standard Restore Nuget step was trying to use MsBuild 14 which is not available on VS2017 agents.

Comment: I don't have Hosted VS2017 on mine.

Comment: Maybe it is under deployment

Comment: I confirm that I was able to do a full c#7 build today on a hosted vs2017 agent. Check the agent queue in the options of your build.

Comment: Ya well hopefully this is getting done because mine still only has hosted agent.

Comment: I just checked and I can still only see "Hosted Agent". I also checked the hosted agents page again (link in my question) which was last updated today with the information about the VS2017 agents. I can only assume it's a staggered release.